# Navigator showing at 1970 when first point is null

Tags: highcharts

I've got data being loaded asynchronously from a client. From time to time, null time and value pairs will be received. If this happens, the navigator shows beginning at 1970. 
I've tried setting the initial point to the first timestamp in the navigator series and the problem persists, as the null is in the series being displayed.

Is there a solution you can suggest or a workaround?

Here's my code and [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tt7dp/):

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        chart: {
        },

        navigator: {
            adaptToUpdatedData: false,
            series: {
                name: 'navigator'
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Billy"
        }
        ]
    });

    var data = [[null, null],
                    [Date.UTC(1990,  9, 27), 10 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1990, 10, 10), 20 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1990, 10, 18), 30 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1990, 11,  2), 40 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1990, 11,  9), 50 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1990, 11, 16), 60 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1990, 11, 28), 50],
                    [Date.UTC(1991,  0,  1), 40],
                    [Date.UTC(1991,  0,  8), 30],
                    [Date.UTC(1991,  0, 12), 20],
                    [Date.UTC(1991,  0, 27), 10]]
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].setData(data);
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(chart.xAxis[0].min, chart.xAxis[0].max, true);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a null x value in Highcharts.

If you have no y data for the point, specify your data as (ie) `[Date.UTC(1990,  9, 27), null]`

A null x and null y gives you nothing meaningful, as you don't know when the null value (ie, the problem) occurred.

Comment: True, a null timestamp has little information on it's own. However, when it is in a series of data points of increasing time, we can isolate it to an issue in a time range.We're using non-connected nulls fine right now: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.connectNulls

Comment: I think you are missing my point.  connectNulls applies to null y- values. The null y value is fine.  A null x value serves purpose - there is nothing to connect or skip in the data, if you don't specify the x value.  Your time series doesn't know what time that point is for, and therefore can't skip it, or include it...  by sending [null, null], you are literally telling the chart nothing about where that data point belongs.  And therefore causing errors. How can a chart possibly know when to start a date navigator when the date you give it is null?

Comment: Ah I see your point and agree. At the least, the server needs to send back a timestamp for the value, otherwise it's mixing ordinal and datetime plots on the x-axis, which is a bit crazy. I think it's working for my examples when in the middle of a series, but mostly by luck, rather than design.

Comment: As it turns out, I've seen the same error when all series start with null y, but valid x values. I'll try to create a fiddle to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Why not filter out null/null pairs? If the data has no meaningful use why allow it to be sent to the chart?

Comment: No data is meaningful in our case, as it means something has gone wrong on-site. Highcharts handles this well in other instances, showing a break in the chart where there is no data and we can annotate this for the user so they can preform additional investigation.

Comment: Okay, I can see that. How about you make a second series for just the navigator but have it not include the null points?

Comment: Going forward, that sounds like a good idea that I hadn't thought about. We could work out the common time-base for all series to be displayed and create a time series to represent it on the navigator. Another option which I had being considering was to allow the user to nominate a navigator series themselves, which we could process to remove all nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine this lines:

```
 chart.addSeries({
            name: 'USD to EUR'
        });
    chart.series[0].setData(data);
```

into

```
 chart.addSeries({
    name: 'USD to EUR',
    data:data,
    pointStart: Date.UTC(1990, 9, 27)
});
```

You can use pointStart, but will be better to get rid of null values.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tt7dp/4/

Comment: pointStart is an interesting trick. I can scan for the first non null datetime and set that value. Getting rid of null values would be ideal, but not an option, for the reasons stated above.